# ggplot x variable according to vector

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a large dataset (14295,58). Each column is a different element from the periodic table (e.g. Fe, Ca, Zr) and the rows are arranged according to depth (in mm); the last column is the depth value. I am trying to make a code that can be customized to a given group of elements over a given depth interval but I don't want to have to go through and change a bunch of lines of code everytime I look at a different subset. So far I have created a dataframe called Section:

```
Section <- df[50:100,]
```

and a vector called Elements:

```
Elements <- c("Fe", "Ca", "Zr")
```

I can subsample the Section data frame by:

```
Section %>%
select(., Elements, depth)
```

but now I want to plot this with ggplot and I can't figure out how to call the Elements vector to the x-variable. I tried:

```
Section %>%
select(., Elements, depth) %>%
ggplot() +
geom_path (aes(Elements, depth))
```

but the arguments don't have the same length. How can I plot the selected elements from the Elements vector?

Comment: please share your data (or a subset) so people can provide solutions

Comment: Welcome to SO. We can't help you really when we are not able to reproduce your code. have a look how to ask a good question. You won't get a good answer without a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `d <- seq(0, 100, 0.5) 
    Fe <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000)
    Ca <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000)
    Zr <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000)
    Ti <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000)
    Al <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000)

example <- data.frame(d, Fe, Ca, Zr, Ti, Al)`

Comment: Sorry its not in a great format. I'm not sure the best way to provide a dataset after the question has been asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is actually that your data is not formatted in the most useful way (wide vs. long), so you aren't actually giving `ggplot` what you think you are. If you give it a vector as an aesthetic (`Elements` here), it will try its best to plot it. In this case, it will do it if the length matches by just matching up values in `depth` to things in `Elements`. So this works:

```
# Toy Data
df <- data.frame(O = 1:3,
                 Fe = 2:4,
                 Ca = 3:5,
                 Zr = 4:6,
                 depth = 5:7)
Elements <- c('Fe', 'Ca', 'Zr')
ggplot(df) +
    geom_point(aes(x=Elements, y=depth))
```

But it just matches the first `depth` to `'Fe'`, the second `depth` to `'Ca'`, etc. I don't think that's what you are hoping to have happen.

**Long vs Wide Data**

You have separate columns for every all these elements, but do they actually represent different things? You are probably better off re-formatting your data so that all these "element" columns get collapsed into key-value pairs using tidyr:

```
# Wide:
df
  O Fe Ca Zr depth
1 1  2  3  4     5
2 2  3  4  5     6
3 3  4  5  6     7

# Long
library(tidyr)
longDf <- tidyr::gather(df, element, amount, -depth)
longDf
       depth element amount
1      5       O      1
2      6       O      2
3      7       O      3
4      5      Fe      2
5      6      Fe      3
6      7      Fe      4
7      5      Ca      3
8      6      Ca      4
9      7      Ca      5
10     5      Zr      4
11     6      Zr      5
12     7      Zr      6
```

Now you can get the elements you want using `dplyr`'s `filter` (which is also probably a better option for subsetting by `depth`) and use the new `element` column as the x coordinate for plotting:

```
longDf %>% 
    filter(element %in% Elements) %>%
    ggplot() +
        geom_path(aes(x=element, y=depth))
```

I'm not sure what you're expecting the graph to look like, but that should get you started.

Comment: Thanks @Taiki Sakai! That does help to get me started. My issue now is that I want each graphed line to be a different colour. When I added to geom_path 
 `geom_path(aes(x=amount, y=depth), colour = element)`  I got an error saying "object 'element' not found". However, if I run  `test <- longDf %>%  filter(element %in% Elements)`  the resulting dataframe has variable as a column. Any thoughts?

Comment: Strike that last question, I had the colour operation in the wrong bracket

Comment: You need to put `colour = element` inside the `aes` part of the code. This is where `ggplot` looks for the names of columns in the data.frame you supplied as `data`, outside of the `aes` part it will look for objects in your global environment.